# lighttpd authentication before redirection from https to http

Tags: redirect, https, lighttpd

I would like to redirect from https to http **after** authentication so credentials go through a secure channel but everything else is transmitted in plain.

Here it is the relevant part of the conf file:

```
## Auth
# https://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/1/wiki/docs_modauth
# type of backend
# plain, htpasswd, ldap or htdigest
auth.backend               = "htpasswd"
# for htpasswd
auth.backend.htpasswd.userfile = "/etc/apache2/auth.htpwd"
auth.require = ( "" =>
        (
                "method" => "basic",
                "realm" => "Authorization required",
                "require" => "valid-user"
        )
)

## Simple SSL
# https://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/1/wiki/HowToSimpleSSL
$SERVER["socket"] == ":443" {
        ssl.engine = "enable"
        ssl.pemfile = "/etc/lighttpd/certs/lighttpd.pem"
}

## Redirect from https to http
# https://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/1/wiki/HowToRedirectHttpToHttps
# https://redmine.lighttpd.net/boards/2/topics/3988
$HTTP["scheme"] == "https" {
        $HTTP["host"] =~ "([^:/]+)" {
                url.redirect = ( "^/(.*)" => "http://%1:1234/$1" )
        }
}
```

So far redirection is executed **before** authentication.

Any ideas?

lighttpd 1.4.35 on Linux 4.1.19

Comment: A bit irrelevant, but what if somebody goes directly to http without authentication? I don't see you setting any kind of token/cookie.

Comment: True. But now it does not bother me.

Answer (score 0):

I answer myself.

My question makes no sense. `HTTP` is a [stateless](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13200152/why-say-that-http-is-a-stateless-protocol) protocol, so even if I could authenticate over `SSL` and then jump to `HTTP`, credentials will always be send in plain in subsequent `HTTP` requests.